# Are there other "approval" services for other email providers, like SenderID for Hotmail?

Tags: spam, email, bulk-email, hotmail, live

This question comes from: [How to avoid Hotmail/Live rejections for (legit) large volume eMailing?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/695/how-to-avoid-hotmail-live-rejections-for-legit-large-volume-emailing)

I never knew about this for Hotmail and I'm wondering if there are similar services for Google, Yahoo or others. I work on a few newsletter managers and I want to make sure the emails are getting to their recipients.

Answer (score 1):

Coding Horror had a pretty thorough discussion of [sending e-mail through code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html). It includes a reference to the Port 25 verifier that might be useful.