# Hotmail — avoid sign up confirmation / lost password being marked as spam

Tags: email, spam, bulk-email, hotmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I prevent my mail from being recognized as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-could-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-recognized-as-spam)

When sending legit large volume Emails from our IP (e.g. for sign up confirmation or Lost password) it gets marked as Junk in Hotmail.

In the past, there was the Sender ID SPF Record Submission Form, where you could put yourself on the radar of Microsoft. See [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/697) old discussion. However, as of April 2012 this has been abandoned.

Any hints what to do now? What is a good way to contact the Hotmail team?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate. This refers to hotmail. Also, Hotmail changed its policy in April 2012, so this is very current.

Comment: The original question you asked was an exact dupe, would suggest you delete this one and repost your update as a new question with a better title.